# Passing function parameters to SQLiteDatabase query (specifically whereArgs)

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

I have a peculiar issue when attempting to pass String values to the whereArgs parameter in the SQLiteDatabase.query() method.
I am attempting to check a connected Wi-Fi SSID against a list of stored SSIDs in a database.

The value (string) of the name of the SSID is obtained from the `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID()` method as follows:

```
String ssid = info.getSSID();
```

This string is then passed into a database helper which attempts to grab the row with the name of the SSID. (The row also contains other saved data about the Wi-Fi network which is relevant to the application).

The problem is that I can't seem to get the `ssid` parameter to be accepted by the whereArgs[] parameter in the query() function.

As it is below, connecting to a network called `_The Cloud` results in the first Log.d to read `D/ssidGiven: "_The Cloud"`, and the second one reads `D/Cursor Count: 0` despite there being an entry with that name in the database.

```
public String getSSIDStatus(String ssid) {
    Log.d("test",ssid);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String status = null;

    try {
        Log.d("ssidGiven",ssid);
        String[] matchWith = new String[] {ssid};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(SSID_TABLE_NAME, SSID_COLUMN_NAMES, SSID_COLUMN_NAMES[0]+"=?", matchWith, null, null, null);
        Log.d("Cursor Count", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        ...
```

If I swap out the matchWith variable to contain the hardcoded string

```
String[] matchWith = new String[] {"_The Cloud"};
```

it works perfectly and shows the Cursor count being one.

Why can't I pass the variable, despite it being (as far as I can see), identical to the hardcoded string?

Comment: Most likely, the value is not actually identical. Use `equals()` to confirm.

Comment: "_The Cloud" on the logcat realy means: "\"_The Cloud\"", i mean ssid.length() == 12, not 10

Comment: @pskink This solved my problem! Thanks. Totally overlooked it!